# Как записать выборку из таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как, в одном запросе, записать выборку по имени оператора из таблицы один, если имя оператора нужно найти во второй таблице по имени клиента

```
'SELECT `operator` FROM `table2` WHERE `client` = clientname'
'SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`operator` = `table2`.`operator`'
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под словами `записать выборку`

Comment: select, получить строки с таблицы 2, где имя оператора = имени оператора из таблицы 1, которое нужно найти по соответствующему клиенту

Comment: а для клиента какая колонка и в какой таблице?

Comment: напишите в вопросе какие колонки есть и по каким критериям нужно сделать запрос

Comment: есть таблица 2 со списком клиентов, столбцы: ClientName, HimOperator. так же есть таблица 1 , столбцы: OperatorName, и еще 5 столбцов , как мне получить строки из таблицы 1 с нужным мне оператором если я знаю только имя клиента

Comment: Такой ответ подойдет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример для `UPDATE` запроса с `JOIN` который вы хотели:

```
UPDATE `table1` JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`operator`=`table2`.`operator` SET (`table1`.`column1` = "Вася", `table1`.`column2` = "Петя") WHERE `table2`.`ClientName` = "Оля"
```

Comment: если есть дополнительное условие по таблице 1 его вписывать в join? JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`operator`=`table2`.`operator`  AND ........?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 не смог понять что вы хотите сказать но для `JOIN` условие пишется в `ON`, после него шел `SET` и в конце стандартно `WHERE` условие которые не связаны с `JOIN`, если для `JOIN` нужно еще условие, после `ON` напишите по очереди с `AND` или `OR`, это в зависимости от того что вам нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется такой запрос вам подойдет:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table1.operator=table2.operator WHERE table2.ClientName = "Петя";
```

Comment: `left ` в данном случае не нужен. достаточно обычного `join`

Comment: @ArtGrek13 но ведь не мешает?

Comment: Ну в MySQL не мешает, но в некоторых СУБД, например в ораклах как минимум до 9 оптимизатор для left шел по другому пути, который значительно замедлял выборку. Потому как формально тут написано: "выбери _все_ из таблицы 1, попытайся подклеить подходящие записи из таблицы 2, после чего выброси все выбранное, что не относится к пете"

Comment: @Mike честно говоря не понял вас.

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan а такой способ и для update можно использовать?

Comment: @Mike да, мы про `MySql` говорили, и я то же так помнил))

Comment: @ArtGrek13 да так то же можно привязать таблицы для `UPDATE` запроса

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Я имел ввиду, что для данной задачи достаточно `select * from tab1 JOIN tab2 on ... where ...`, без указания слова left. потому как слово left предназначено для поиска таких записей в Table1 которые могут иметь подходящие записи в Table2, так и не имеющие подходящих записей. Стоит понимать различия разных видов join и использовать именно то, которое действительно необходимо в конкретном случае. http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Да я понял почему вы это сказали, но в данном примере оно не мешало

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan вы не могли бы показать пример с update в ту же таблицу с теми же условиями?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 если скажете какие колонки нужно обновить

Comment: table1: OperatorName, column1, column2; table2: ClientName, HimOperator; я знаю ClientName, обновить надо  column1 и column2